# First order ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am confused as to what exactly this question is asking for.

Consider the equation for y = y(s):
sy' − y = 0.

1. Define x(t) = y(e^t)
   Find an first order ODE satisfied by x.
2. Find all solutions to sy' − y = 0.

I found the general solution for the second question to be y = C*s but I am unsure how to find an ODE that satisfies x using the definiton given. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's substitute $s=e^t$. Then $x=y(s)$ and $x'=e^t y'(e^t)=sy'(s)$. Now $x'-x=sy'(s)-y(s)=0$, which is the same as the given equation. So the answer is $x'-x=0$.